# Use JDBI to get Postgres Array Data

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbi

I have a java program using JDBI (a JDBC wrapper) to access a PostgreSQL database. One of the columns is of the array data type `(mycolumn integer[])`.

What the heck to I use in my mapper class? I thought `resultSet.getArray("mycolumn")` would be the right thing to do, but I'm not sure how to get the data out of the `java.sql.Array` object that gets returned.

Any hints or good links on how to do this?

Comment: Hint: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html , `Array.getArray()`.

Comment: It returns an Object though...I don't know what type to cast it to and the docs didn't make it clearer for me.

Comment: The underlying array type is determined by the database field type. You can get the details from the JDBC metadata APIs. Alternately, `getClass()` on the object and inspect it that way.

Comment: Apparently getArray requires an open connection. Why I'm not sure since when I inspect the Array during debug I see a private field with the data in it. Its a jdbc4Array btw

Comment: I seem to recall that's a future-proofing and JDBC compliance thing. From memory getArray is allowed to lazily fetch the array data from the server, so while PgJDBC doesn't currently do so it doesn't want people assuming it will never do so in future. You should get your data mapper code to fetch and unwrap the array before returning the connection to the pool.

Comment: That's not really viable with the ondemand JDBI queries...happily I have influence over the schema so I will just get them to store this info as strings.

Comment: You might want to file a bug against JDBI too, then, with a simple test case attached. If it can't cope with standard-compliant arrays that's a pretty big problem in a tool that claims to make JDBC easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
        Array array = resultSet.getArray("mycolumn");
        return nonNull(array) ? (Integer[])array.getArray() : null ;
```

Comment: How do I register that piece of code so `@MapResultAsBean` can use it?

Comment: We can't use @MapResultAsBean for this problem. We need to write a mapper

Comment: What I mean is I want a Bean with a `List<Integer>` field (or even `int[]` if `List` is not possible) and have the bean mapper fill that field from the `ResultSet`. I've actually done this by taking the existing mapper and adding a type to the existing code, but it would be awesome if the existing mapper was extensible.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no support available of collections in BeanMapper.  You can try this library http://manikandan-k.github.io/jdbi_folder .