# How to convert 2d array from PostgreSQL DB to java 2d array using JDBI?

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, dropwizard, jdbi

How can I convert a 2d char array from my Postgres DB to a native Java char[][]? This is my attempt based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093398/use-jdbi-to-get-postgres-array-data):

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.skife.jdbi.v2.StatementContext;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.tweak.ResultSetMapper;

public class GameMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Game>{
    public Game map(int index, ResultSet resultSet, StatementContext statementContext) throws SQLException
    {
        Array board = resultSet.getArray("BOARD");
        return new Game(resultSet.getInt("ID"),
                        resultSet.getInt("WHOSE_TURN"),
                        resultSet.getInt("WINNER"),
                        (char[][]) board.getArray());
    }
}
```

**Data class:**

```
public class Game {
    protected int id; 
    protected int whoseTurn;
    protected int winner;
    protected char[][] board;

    public Game(int id, int turn, int winner, char[][] board ) {
        this.id=id;
        this.whoseTurn=turn;
        this.winner=winner;
        this.board=board;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public int getWhoseTurn() {
        return whoseTurn;
    }

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public int getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    public char[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }   
}
```

**DAO:**

```
@RegisterMapper(GameMapper.class)
public interface GameDAO {

    @SqlUpdate("create table if not exists GAMES (ID integer, WHOSE_TURN varchar(10), WINNER varchar(10), BOARD char(1)[][])")
    void createTableIfNotExists();

    @SqlUpdate("insert into GAMES (ID, WHOSE_TURN, WINNER, BOARD) values (:id, :whoseTurn, :winner, :board)")
    void insert(@BindBean Game game);
}
```

But this results in a cast error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [[C
```

Do I need to use [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [[Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to [[C

[Time to learn what Java array type names mean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayComponents.html).

`[` is `array-of`. So `[[` is array-of array-of, i.e. both type names are 2-d arrays.

`L` indicates a reference type, followed by the class name.

`C` is the primitive type `char`.

So here, we see that you are attempting to cast two-dimensional array of `java.lang.String` to a two-dimensional array of `char`. That doesn't make any sense. It looks like JDBI maps the Java data type `char` to an SQL string type like `character` or `character varying`, (verify by checking the table in the database). If so, the JDBC driver will return that from the database as `java.lang.String`.

So you need to either override that mapping to use the database data type `"char"` - a single character - or, more simply, assert that the strings are one character long and unpack them into a character. So you'll have to copy the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at postgres JDBC driver. If the column type is CHAR or VARCHAR it tries to convert it to String array.

```
    else if (type == Types.CHAR || type == Types.VARCHAR)
    {
        Object[] oa = null;
        ret = oa = (dims > 1 ? (Object[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(String.class, dimsLength) : new String[count]);
    }
```

So you will get 2D String array. You need to convert it to char[][] in the mapper.